# React-Admin ReferenceInput no longer triggers onChange

Tags: javascript, react-hook-form, react-admin

I'm using React-Admin and have a [SimpleForm](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SimpleForm.html) where I want to trigger some generic action any time any of form fields are changed, including a [ReferenceInput](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceInput.html) selection field.

I'm upgrading from React-Admin version 2.9 to 4.x. In the former version I had an *onChange* control on a SimpleForm and it triggered when any form field was changed, including ReferenceInput fields. In the new version, changing the ReferenceInput dropdown selection *no longer* triggers the onChange event.

Why is that? And is there some way to get it working again?

```
...
import { 
  Create, SimpleForm, TextInput, ReferenceInput, SelectInput
} from 'react-admin';

const doSomething = () => {
    // something
};

const ItemCreate = ({ dataProvider, ...props }) => (
  <>
    <Create title="Create Class" {...props}>

      <SimpleForm onChange={doSomething}>

        <TextInput source="name" label="Name"/>
        
        <!-- no longer triggers the onChange event (doSomething) -->
        <ReferenceInput label="Item" source="item" reference="items">
          <SelectInput optionText={(choice) => `${choice.itemName}`} />
        </ReferenceInput>

      </SimpleForm>

    </Create>
  </>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using [react-hook-form](https://www.react-hook-form.com/)'s `useFormContext()`, as suggested by @MaxAlex.

I was able to avoid using a pseudo-component. I basically did the following:

- remove `onChange`, as it no longer seems to work with React-Admin's ReferenceInput
- move the input component outside of the `SimpleForm` (when I put `useFormContext()` directly into the component that contains SimpleForm it returns null)
- inside a `useEffect` in that separate input component, use `useFormContext`, and/or other react-hook-form functionality (e.g., *dirtyFields* or *useWatch*) to monitor form field changes and take action based on that

Example:

```
...
import { 
  Create, SimpleForm, TextInput, ReferenceInput, SelectInput
} from 'react-admin';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

const MyInput = () => {
  const formContext = useFormContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    const { dirtyFields } = formContext.formState;

    // if the user changes fieldA, modify fieldB
    if (
      Object.keys(dirtyFields).includes('fieldA')
    ) {
      formContext.setValue('fieldB', 1);
    }
  });
  return (
    <ReferenceInput label="Form Field B" source="fieldB" reference="items">
      <SelectInput optionText={(choice) => `${choice.itemName}`} />
    </ReferenceInput>
  );
};

...
const ItemCreate = () => {
  return (
    <Create>
      <SimpleForm>
        // other form fields, including fieldA
        <MyInput />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  );
};
...
```

I've found that, in addition to addressing the issue of `onChange` no longer working on my `ReferenceInput` field, *react-hook-form* seems to provide more granular control than `onChange` did.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere inside the form you can call:

```
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'
...
const { watch } = useFormContext()
watch((data, { name, type }) => console.log(data, name, type))
```

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch

Comment: This looks helpful, but it gives me "react_hook_form__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useFormContext() is null". I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, finding a place to call useFormContext is not a trivial task, I created a pseudo-component that returned null and called useFormContext inside it.

Comment: Ugh. Do you know of any good examples on github or guidance anywhere?

Comment: No, it might be worth asking this question on react-admin github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [validate](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SimpleForm.html#validate) prop instead of onChange in the `SimpleForm`.

And please, read the [Form validation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html) section in the docs, this should help you as well.